# Am having an error message Could not load type 'Microsoft.Samples.Web.ImageOptimizationModule when using sprites

Tags: asp.net, sprite

I have an error while using ap sprites.Am not able to do it.

i have added the following code in web.config

```
<system.webServer>
     <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <add type="Microsoft.Samples.Web.ImageOptimizationModule"
       name ="Microsoft.Samples.Web.ImageOptimizationModule"/>
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>

  <system.web>
    <pages>
      <controls>
       <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="Microsoft.Web.Samples" assembly="Microsoft.Web.Samples.ImageSprite" />

      </controls>

    </pages>
    <httpModules>
      <add type="Microsoft.Samples.Web.ImageOptimizationModule"
           name="Microsoft.Samples.Web.ImageOptimizationModule" />
    </httpModules>
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    </system.web>
```

and i have also created a folder App_Sprites.And added reference of `ImageSprite` and `ImageOptimizationFramework`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made the following changes in my web.config file and its works fine and also added `WebForms.dll` reference.

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />

    <pages>
      <controls>
        <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="Microsoft.Web.Samples" assembly="Microsoft.Web.Samples.ImageSprite" />
      </controls>
    </pages>

    <httpModules>
      <add type="Microsoft.Web.Samples.ImageOptimizationModule"
           name="Microsoft.Web.Samples.ImageOptimizationModule"/>
    </httpModules>
  </system.web>

  <system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <add type="Microsoft.Web.Samples.ImageOptimizationModule"
           name="Microsoft.Web.Samples.ImageOptimizationModule"/>
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

For Detail Explanation of Sprite along with the demo and Sample Download see following link
https://web.archive.org/web/20211020150102/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/101310-1.aspx

Answer (score 0):

This is mostly a guess, but you might have to qualify the type name in your declarations with the assembly name.

I don't know what the assembly name for `Microsoft.Samples.Web.ImageOptimizationModule` is, but let's say it's `Microsoft.Web.Samples.ImageSprite`:

```
 <add type="Microsoft.Web.Samples.ImageOptimizationModule, Microsoft.Web.Samples.ImageSprite"
   name ="Microsoft.Web.Samples.ImageOptimizationModule"/>
```

Comment: Was that the actual name of the assembly?

Comment: namespace="Microsoft.Web.Samples" assembly="Microsoft.Web.Samples.ImageSprite"

Comment: OK, I'll modify my answer to reflect the real value.

Comment: Actually, I just noticed:  you have the type as `Microsoft.Samples.Web.ImageOptimizationModule`, but I suspect it's supposed to be `Microsoft.Web.Samples.ImageOptimizationModule`!